# Envíar Valor ingresado de una caja de texto a otra en una página diferente en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html5, json, php7

soy nuevo en la comunidad y actualmente me encuentro trabajando con un pequeño formulario que contiene solamente una caja de texto y dos selectbox.
Ambos selectbox tienen una validación en dónde me mostrarán una pagina diferente de acuerdo a su selección (ya funcional) y la caja de texto solamente llevara escrito un pin por el usuario. 
Mi intención es que ese valor ingresado sea enviado a un nuevo textbox localizado en cualquiera de las páginas seleccionadas por el select box pero no logro hacerlo, ya intente con javascript pero nada. Les dejo los códigos correspondientes esperando su ayuda, saludos¡

Formulario:

```
  <form action="validar.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <label>PIN Empresarial<span class='required'>*</span></label>
  <input type='text' form-control name='pin' id='pin' required=""> 

  <label>Te gusta la música?:</label>
     <select class='form-control' name='select1'>
        <option value='si' id="si1" name="si">SI</option>
        <option value='no' id="no0" name="no">NO</option>
     </select>

  <label>Te gusta leer?:</label>
     <select class='form-control' name='select2'>
         <option value='si' id="si11" name="si">SI</option>
         <option value='no' id="no00" name="no">NO</option>
   </select>
<button type='submit'>Enviar</button>
```

Código Validar.php dónde se validad las selecciones y se envía a la página correspondiente que contendrá la caja de texto que recibirá lo escrito por el usuario en id='pin'.

```
<?php
 $selectBox1 = $_POST["select1"]; 
 $selectBox2 = $_POST["select2"];

 if ($selectBox1 == "si"  && $selectBox2 == "si") {
header('Location: pagina1.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "si"  && $selectBox2 == "no") {
header('Location: pagina2.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "no"  && $selectBox2 == "no"){
header('Location: pagina3.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "no"  && $selectBox2 == "si"){
header('Location: pagina4.php');
}
else {
    header('Location: formulario.php');
} 
?>
```

Pagina 1,2,3,4 contendrán la caja de texto que recibirá de formulario, dependiendo de la selección selectbox del usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes mandarlo como parametro en la url asi:

```
<?php
 $selectBox1 = $_POST["select1"]; 
 $selectBox2 = $_POST["select2"];
 $pin = $_POST["pin"];

 if ($selectBox1 == "si"  && $selectBox2 == "si") {
header('Location: pagina1.php?pin=' . $pin);
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "si"  && $selectBox2 == "no") {
header('Location: pagina2.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "no"  && $selectBox2 == "no"){
header('Location: pagina3.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "no"  && $selectBox2 == "si"){
header('Location: pagina4.php');
}
else {
    header('Location: formulario.php');
} 
?>
```

Comment: Pero lo que yo quiero es que el texto ingresado en la  caja de texto del formulario aparezca en la otra caja de texto alojado en la página correspondiente.

Comment: @alanfmc ya te dio la solución solo es por intuición hacer esto: `<input type='text' form-control name='pin' id='pin' value="<?php echo $_GET['pin']; ?>"  required="">` así colocas el valor de tu pin en la caja de texto de la página a dónde se te dirigió.

Comment: @VickMuñoz me arroja este error dentro del input recibido br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: pin

Comment: Logré envíar el valor de la variable por la url pero no me abre la página correspondiente                                                                                             
     Not Found
The requested URL pagina1.php pin=123 was not found on this server.

Comment: Te falta agregar el `?` así: `pagina1.php?pin=123`.

Comment: Sigue sin enviarlo,seguí todo el código.